# Add user role(s) based on product IDs and quantity when WooCommerce order status is completed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders, user-roles

I'm trying to assign user roles based on a few different criteria:

- If a user purchases Item-A, user-role-a is assigned.
- If a user purchases Item-B, user-role-b is assigned.
- If a user purchases 2 or more of Item-B, user-role-c is also assigned.

So multiple user roles can be assigned. Based on [Change User Role After Purchasing Product](https://wpglorify.com/change-user-role-after-purchasing-product/), this is my attempt:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase' );

function wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

// CHILD PRODUCT MAKES PRIMARY ADULT ROLE
    
    $product_id = 50; // that's the child product ID

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            // Add new role
            $user->add_role( 'primary-adult' );
        }
    }

// ADULT PRODUCT MAKES ADULT ROLE
    
    $product_id = 43; // that's the adult product ID
    
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            // Add new role
            $user->add_role( 'adult' );
        }
    }   
    
}
```

With my code I was able to get a bit of a solution (assign roles based on purchased product IDs), but I still need to be able to assign a role based on the quantity of a purchased item. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to answering your question, I also modified and optimized your code a bit:

- It is not necessary to go through the order items again per condition, instead put the conditions in the loop
- `$item->get_quantity()` can be used to know the quantity
- Multiple roles can be assigned to the same user, based on the product IDs

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Product IDs
    $item_a = 30;
    $item_b = 813;

    // Is a order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Get user
        $user = $order->get_user();

        // User is NOT empty
        if ( ! empty ( $user ) ) {
            // Loop through order items
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $key => $item ) {
                // Item A
                if ( $item->get_product_id() == $item_a ) {
                    // Add user role
                    $user->add_role( 'user-role-a' );
                // Item B
                } elseif ( $item->get_product_id() == $item_b ) {
                    // Add user role
                    $user->add_role( 'user-role-b' );

                    // Quantity equal to or greater than
                    if ( $item->get_quantity() >= 2 ) {
                        // Add user role
                        $user->add_role( 'user-role-c' );                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 2 );
```